# Accessing BIRT Elements from script

Tags: java, javascript, report, birt, report-designer

I have BIRT Text element in Master page:
eg: elementID : 175
    element name :myElement

also I have a PI chart: and once I click on its categories I want to invoke a script and write some text to the "TEXT" element. I tried as below: but both didn't work

```
  reportContext.getDesignHandle().getElementByID(175).text = "some text" 

  reportContext.getDesignHandle().findElement("myElement").text = "some text"
```

Appreciate your help on this